# Can't validate my APP with iTunes, which names and identifiers must match itunesconnect?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, tvos

I have an tvOs App on iTunes, and I am now trying to upload (validate) an improved version of that App.

I get the error message:

> iTunes Store Operation Failed. Unable to process the app at this time
> due to general error

When I research this error message on Stack Overflow, I get the advice to be patient and try later. **But I have been patient for a week!** Meanwhile, I have been able to validate several other Apps.  **I conclude that Apple's server is not congested, and that my certificate is valid!**

I have noticed that the upload dialog **does not show the proper icon** of the App (see below). In my experience, the icon placeholder usually displays the icon of the previous App, i.e. the App present att App Store. **Since no icon is displayed, I guess that Apple does not identify my App correctly!**

[image]

I know that I have the **correct bundle identifier** (reverse url followed by a name). But that identifier also identifies an iOS version of the tvOS App (so it does not uniquely pinpoint my tvOS App).

**I do not know if all other identifiers (display name, etc) in my project are correct!**

So my question is: Which things, names and identifiers, etc, must be correct to upload a new version of an App to iTunes? **And how can I find out the correct values of those things by inspecting the App's page on *itunesconnect* ?**

Comment: Your bundle ID and new version number must match what you have set in ITC as the new version.

Comment: yes, thanks,  but my bundle identifier (reverse url and name) dose match, and also the version (1.4)

Comment: I'm in the same weird spot where I've been stuck for days trying to figure out why my tvOS update doesn't validate (error about provisioning that makes no sense) or upload (error about missing icons, which are demonstrably false after inspecting the payload). I also have the same case where my iOS and tvOS app share the same bundle identifier (to get universal purchase capability). I wish I had an answer for you, but will follow this thread and report back if I figure anything out. Very frustrating.